# Getting error in comparison and variable assignment

Tags: bash

I am new in scripting. Getting error in comparison and variable assignment.

File cat tmp_queues_entries_in.txt contains multiple rows like below:

```
transadapt_receive_969,=,444189812719624,1012980.21600
```

#### Code:-

```
for k in `cat tmp_queues_entries_stuck.txt`
do
q_name=`echo $k |cut -d ',' -f 1|sed -e 's/ //g'`  
declare -i  qtime=`echo $k |cut -d ',' -f 4|cut -d '.' -f 1|sed -e 's/ //g'` 
echo $qtime "Queue Stuck time"
declare -i  qtimee=`echo $qtime`
let stuckT=`echo "scale = 3; $qtimee / 3600" | bc -l`
half_hr=0.5
One_hr=1
if ([ $stuckT '>' $half_hr ]| bc -l)  && ([ $stuckT '<' $One_hr ]| bc -l)
then
echo "$q_name is stuck with $stuckT Min's" >>tmp_stuck_q_Minutes.txt 
else
if [ $( echo "$stuckT > 1" | bc )]
then
echo "$q_name is stuck with more than $stuckT Hours" >> tmp_stuck_q_Hours.txt 
fi
done
echo "No files Stuck with more than half hour." | tee -a  ${ERROR_L}**
```

#### Getting Error :-

```
test.sh: line 70: stuckT=281.383: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".383")
'[' '>' 0.5 ']'
test.sh: line 83: [: >: unary operator expected
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
'[' ']'
echo 'No files Stuck with more than half hour.'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have posted the code which you tried, kindly post the sample of input and sample of output too in your post for our better understanding of this question.

Comment: I can't understand what your code is supposed to do. Run shellcheck on your code. Google it.

Comment: In expressions such as `[ $stuckT '>' $half_hr ]` always put variables in double quotes: `"$stuckT"`, because this way even if variable is empty string, then `[` command will still consider it an argument. Without quotes expression may become smth like `[ < 123]` which is a syntax error.

Comment: Hello Mr Morton, I want to know the value of "StuckTime" is in between 0.5 and 1 then print the stuck value with q_name if not then enter in to second loop.

Comment: If you explained what the fields on each line represent, and what you are trying to do in plain English (no code), I suspect 2-3 lines of `awk` would readily solve your question in a tiny fraction of the time your script currently uses, and also be mych simpler to read and maintain. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks. let's assume I have a value "stuckT=6.425567" (this value may differ in each case) and I just want to know whether this value comes in to the range of 0.5 to 1.0 or above than 1 need both the conditions out put in 2 different file.

Comment: Huh? Sorry, I still don't understand. You don't have that value in your file. Please show 4-5 lines of input file, describing what each field means and then show what output you expect and why.